# Connect to a website using Python

Tags: python

Let's say I want to connect an app I created to a website (SSL) to get values from the content at a certain page.
How can I do it?

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  Step 2.  Use `urllib2`.  Step 3.  Close this question.  Here are a lot of questions exactly like this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+urllib2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httplib2 if you wanna make https call. Check out the doc for more info.

--Sai

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more complex you could use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), which is a Python library that simulates a browser. So you can interact with the page just like with a normal browser (in case there's no simple direct URL you could retrieve).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use urllib2 which also supports HTTPS connections (if your python installation supports SSL). And  BeautifulSoup library (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for parsing content of web pages.